# New Activity: Why Android Studio wants to create a Blank Activity for "Wear OS"?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio when I want to make a new (blank) activity via the context menu, it always makes one for "Wear OS". Is this normal? How can I prevent this?
I don't do anything with Wear OS.

My only solution is to do it by hand by creating the Java and Layout classes separately and update the Manifest file.

Answer (score 12):

I think its **`Empty activity`** and not blank activity.I also had the same issue when i tried to create a blank activity it created a activity for wear os.
Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 5):

I'm also facing the same problem, when creating a new blank activity, it wants to create a wearOS activity. I think this is a bug in Android studio 4.0.1

Select `Empty Ativity` instead of `Blank Activity` and it works as normal

Answer (score 0):

cuz it show how google product works (Complexity out of control)